# How to order contacts by last message date with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a chat app in nodejs with Sequelize for my db.

Everything works great but when i try to show all user friends ordered by the last message date i have a bug.

To get the users with there messages it works with associations but ordering doesn't.
Here is my function to get messages:

```
const getFriends = (id, limit) => {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
       const user = await Follows.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.or]: {
                    follower_id: id,
                    followed_id: id
                },
            },
            include: Messages
            order: [[Messages, 'createdAt', 'DESC']],
            limit
        })
        resolve(user)
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e)
    }

})
}
```

So Seqeulize does the query but not in the way that I want to.
Here is the query generated by Sequelize:

```
SELECT `follows`.*,
       `messages`.*
FROM (
   SELECT `follows`.* FROM `follows`
   WHERE (
         `follows`.`follower_id` = 3
            OR
         `follows`.`followed_id` = 3
   )
   AND `follows`.`reciprocal` = true
   LIMIT 1
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages` ON `follows`.`id` = `messages`.`pairId`
ORDER BY `messages`.`createdAt` DESC;
```

As you see here the `ORDER BY messages.createdAt DESC;` happens at the end, but after the `FROM` you can see he does a query to the table i'm already querying.

**Which is not LOGIC !!**

I would like to my sql query to look like that:

```
SELECT `follows`.*,
       `messages`.*
FROM `follows`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages` ON `follows`.`id` = `messages`.`pairId`
WHERE (
      `follows`.`follower_id` = 3
         OR
      `follows`.`followed_id` = 3
)
AND `follows`.`reciprocal` = true
ORDER BY `messages`.`createdAt` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That means that I want my `where` and my `limit` to be in the parent query and not in the `FROM` query.
I really don't know how to do this with Sequelize and didn't find someone having same issue on the internet.
I would be really happy to have some help!

Comment: This kind of aliasing is just asking for trouble. Pity anyone who has to maintain this.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm really sorry. I just copy/pasted Sequelized queries but i've changed them and know you can read them easly. Sorry :(

Comment: The original query has a LIMIT clause without an ORDER BY clause. That doesn't make much sense. In consequence, it's hard to know what you're really after, so I refer you again to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy I found the answer.
I just needed to add `subQuery:false` and it worked as I wanted !